# Time issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, msvcrt

My program is working with input() from user. I want to print `"hey,are you there?"` when the user hasn't written anything in 5 seconds. For example, the user writes something, and stops typing. If the user waits more than 5 seconds, then I want to print `"hey,are you there?"`. So far I tried this:

```
while True:
    start=time.time()
    x=input("enter something")
    end=time.time()
    dif=end-start
    if 5<dif:
        print("hey are you there?")
```

It didn't work as I expected, because it waits for the user. It's writing `"hey are you there?"` after the user wrote something. But I expect that when the user doesn't type anything, it also means `x==False`, I want to warn the user.

**Update** I tried this one:

```
import msvcrt
import time

time1 = 0

print('enter something: ')

while not msvcrt.kbhit():
    time.sleep(1)
    time1 +=1
    if time1 == 5:
        print("hey are you there?")

while msvcrt.kbhit():
    x = input()
```

It didn't work either. It printed `"hey are you there?"` after 5 seconds even `x==True`. So far no solution, hope I explained what I need.

Comment: This is going to be exceedingly more difficult than you think it is. Refer to this [relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1425/) where some programming problems are difficult to gauge just how difficult they are! This is a far cry from "virtually impossible," but there's no way to do this without exploring threading and a constant read from stdin.

Comment: I tried threading also, still couldnt find any solution.

Comment: I would approach this by building a thread that listens for `msvcrt.kbhit()` and keeps track of the last time a button was pressed in an infinite loop until it receives a poison pill from a message. If the current time is ever 5s longer than the last kbhit, it should put a message in stdout and set its last time to now. When the user finishes entry, the main thread should sent the poison pill.

Comment: Where is the stackoverflow Python masters meh :-/ I really want to fix this thing

Comment: I could put something together but I'm at work at the moment and don't have the time to spare. I'll bookmark and come back later in case no one has answered yet

Comment: Although it's mostly for networking, you might try the [eventlet module](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html) and make the print be in the exception

Comment: @kbickar can you tell me how to import that module

Comment: @qqvc: `pip install eventlet` then `import eventlet`, however that's not how I'd do this....

Comment: You need to download/install it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eventlet/0.15.2 has a download link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this works, but I'm using python 2.7:

```
    import threading, time

    class ValueGetter(object):
        def __init__(self, wait_time_sec = 5.0):
            self.stop_flag = True
            self.wait_time_sec = wait_time_sec

        def get_value(self):
            self.stop_flag = False
            p = threading.Thread(target=self.print_uthere)
            p.start()
            retval = raw_input('enter something:\n')
            self.stop_flag = True
            p.join()
            return retval

        def print_uthere(self):
            tprint = tnow = time.clock()
            while not self.stop_flag:
                if tnow > (tprint + self.wait_time_sec):
                    print 'Are you there???'
                    tprint = time.clock()
                time.sleep(0.01)
                tnow = time.clock()

    v = ValueGetter()
    print v.get_value()
```

Here is a modified version that will reset the 5 sec timer whenever they enter a key.  Windows only though.

```
import threading, time, msvcrt, sys

class ValueGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, wait_time_sec = 5.0):
        self.stop_flag = True
        self.wait_time_sec = wait_time_sec
        self.tprint = self.tnow = time.clock()

    def get_value(self):
        self.stop_flag = False
        p = threading.Thread(target=self.print_uthere)
        p.start()
        print 'enter something:'
        retval = ''
        ch = ''
        while not ch == '\r':
            retval += ch
            ch = msvcrt.getch()
            sys.stdout.write(ch)
            self.tprint = time.clock()
        print
        self.stop_flag = True
        p.join()
        return retval

    def print_uthere(self):
        self.tprint = self.tnow = time.clock()
        while not self.stop_flag:
            if self.tnow > (self.tprint + self.wait_time_sec):
                print 'Are you there???'
                self.tprint = time.clock()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.tnow = time.clock()

v = ValueGetter()
print v.get_value()
```

Comment: The downside to this method is if the user is in the middle of typing something when the 5 sec expires, you're still going to print the message.

Comment: Its not different than others, still waiting for input from user first.

Comment: If the user doesn't finish entering in 5 sec, it will print the message.  And every 5 sec after that.

Comment: it doesnt, waiting for input

Comment: The thread is running while waiting for the user input and it will print "are you there" every 5 sec until it is stopped.  Have you run this code?

Comment: I did, second codes throws an error.Still not the solution

Comment: what error does it throw?  Is it the print statements?  You can update those for python 3.  I have run these both in a clean 2.7 shell, and both work.

Comment: byte error not print..also as you said its repeating the warning massage after and after

Comment: Well, I don't have Python 3 installed anywhere.  Maybe someone else can get it working in Python 3 and edit my answer.  I didn't think these modules were that different in Python 3.

Comment: I tried it in Python 3, I just push f5 and this is what happening:http://i.hizliresim.com/n5kr4B.jpg . just push f5 nothing typed or did

Comment: @qqvc I'm not sure what exactly the issue with this code is, but he's using `msvcrt` to emulate the call to `input` so we can monitor the keyboard. I can work that into MY implementation to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Having trouble getting `msvcrt.kbhit` to register and don't have time to debug at the moment, so I can't detect a key press to reset the timer. I'll edit when I can figure it out but working on this over my breaks at work since it seems like an interesting problem!

```
import threading
import queue
import msvcrt
import time

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, msg, in_q):
        super().__init__()
        self.__in_q = in_q
        self.msg = msg

    def run(self):
        last_time = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                self.__in_q.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                pass # no poison pill, continue
            else:
                return 0 # poison pill, so end
            cur_time = time.time()
            timedelta = cur_time - last_time
            if timedelta >= 5:
                last_time = cur_time
                print(self.msg)
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                last_time = cur_time
                # THIS BLOCK IS NOT CURRENTLY WORKING
                # POSSIBLY msvcrt.kbhit WILL NOT CAPTURE THIS PROMPT?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = queue.Queue()
    listener = Listener("Are you still there?", q)
    listener.start()
    response = input("enter something: ")
    q.put("poison")
```

Using an implementation of `input` that Fred S hacked in, I was able to get this working as intended. It feels like kludge (and it is) but that's the best I can do on the command line in Windows.

```
import threading
import queue
import msvcrt
import time
import sys

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, in_q, msg=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.__in_q = in_q
        self.msg = msg

    def run(self):
        last_time = time.time()
        while True:
            cur_time = time.time()
            try:
                tmp = self.__in_q.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                pass # no message, OK
            else:
                # message exists. Is it a poison pill?
                if tmp == "poison":
                    # poison pill, kill process
                    return
                else:
                    last_time = time.time()
                    # not poison pill, so refresh the timer
            timedelta = cur_time - last_time
            if timedelta >= 5:
                last_time = cur_time
                print(self.msg)

def new_input(prompt="", out_q=None):
    """Uses msvcrt.getch to simulate Py3's input
    allows you to pass a queue to receive each
    character."""

    result = ""
    print(prompt, end="")
    while True:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        ch = msvcrt.getch().decode()
        sys.stdout.write(ch)
        if out_q:
            out_q.put(ch)
        if "\r" in ch:
            return result
        else:
            result += ch

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = queue.Queue()
    listener = Listener(q, "Are you still there?")
    listener.start()
    result = new_input("enter something: ", q)
    q.put("poison")
    print("You entered " + result)
```

Comment: The warning message still waiting for input from user, not popsup after 5 seconds.Also response=input() must be in a while True: loop.But its a nice step, appriciated.